# template argument deduction for Derived class

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

The code is from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction, now I add void `f(T*)`, and `f(&d)` will call the `f(T*)`.

(1) Can you explain why `f(T*)` is called?

In https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template
it mentions "Template argument deduction takes place after the function template name lookup (which may involve argument-dependent lookup) and before overload resolution. "

The f(T*) is selected because of the 'Exact match' in 'overload resolution', right? 
So in template argument deduction phase, the f(B*) is selected, then in later overload resolution phase, the f(T*) is selected and takes over the f(B*), is this correct?

Thanks

(2) What changes should I make to make the call `f(&d)` to call the `f(B<T>*)`? I also need the `f(T*)` one, so `f(T*)` has to be remained.

```cc
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T> struct B { };
template<class T> struct D : public B<T> { };

template<class T> void f(T*) { cout<< "T*"<< endl; }
template<class T> void f(B<T>*) { cout<< "B<T>*"<< endl; }

int main() {
    D<int> d;
    f(&d);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `f(static_cast<B<int>*>(&d));` is one way.

Comment: Why because deducing `T` (in case 1) as `D<int>` is an exact match.

Comment: Or `f<int>(d)`.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Can you explain why `f(T*)` is called?

Because it's an exact match (when `T` being deduced as `D<int>`). For `f(B<int>*)` to be called the implicit conversion from `D<int>*` to `B<int>*` is required.

> 2. What changes should I make to make the call `f(&d)` to call the `f(B<T>*)`?

You can apply [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae). e.g.

```
// type trait to get the template parameter from template instantiation
template <typename T>
struct get_template_parameter {
    using type = T;
};
template <template <typename> class X, typename T>
struct get_template_parameter<X<T>> {
    using type = T;
};
template <typename T>
using get_template_parameter_t = typename get_template_parameter<T>::type;

// only usable when T is B's instantiation or derived class of B's instantiation
template<class T> 
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_base_of_v<B<get_template_parameter_t<T>>, T>>
f(T*) { cout<< "T*"<< endl; }

template<class T> void f(B<T>*) { cout<< "B<T>*"<< endl; }
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Uy2V2nXcwVZgpZIt)